# bpmn-engine how to call an api instead of method in service task nodejs

Tags: node.js, camunda, bpmn-js, bpmn-engine

I have extended the functionality of service task by adding some few attributes in schema json.

Props like

```
{
   "name": "type",
   "description": "Type of service. Supported is Method Call and API Call",
   "isAttr": true,
   "type": "String"
},
{
   "name": "apiUrl",
   "description": "Url to hit if API Call type",
   "isAttr": true,
   "type": "String"
},
{
    "name": "apiPayload",
    "description": "Payload for API call",
    "isAttr": true,
    "type": "String"
 },
```

Now it can call an api as well based on type.

And i am using [bpmn-engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bpmn-engine) to execute the bpmn flow xml.

But on agi side how can i handle this? In case of service method call, to save the result variable i have used extension like this

```
function bpmnSaveServiceResultToVar(bpmnActivity) {
      // if there is no result from service execution then return
      if (!bpmnActivity.behaviour.resultVariable) {
        return;
      }

      // when this particular activity ends then assign it to a variable
      bpmnActivity.on(EVENT_TYPES.BPMN.END, ({ environment, content }) => {
        const ivrVar = environment.variables.ivrVar;
        // Set the output of the service component into the defined result variable
        set(ivrVar, bpmnActivity.behaviour.resultVariable, content.output[0]);
      });
    }
```